# How to subtract a dataframe from a dataframe based on columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'contact_id': [1,3,4,5,-1],
    'subscription_id': ['AAA', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
});

print(df1)

   contact_id subscription_id
0           1             AAA
1           3             ccc
2           4             ddd
3           5             eee
4          -1             fff
```

2nd dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'contact_id': [1,2,-1],
    'subscription_id': ['AAA', 'bbb', 'fff'],
    'extra': ['we', 'kl', 'op']
});

print(df2)

   contact_id subscription_id extra
0           1             AAA    we
1           2             bbb    kl
2          -1             fff    op
```

**Expected Output**

```
   contact_id subscription_id extra
1           3             ccc   NaN
2           4             ddd   NaN
3           5             eee   NaN
```

**My Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'contact_id': [1,3,4,5,-1],
    'subscription_id': ['AAA', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
});

print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'contact_id': [1,2,-1],
    'subscription_id': ['AAA', 'bbb', 'fff'],
    'extra': ['we', 'kl', 'op']
});

print(df2)

sub = pd.concat([df1, df2, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(sub)
```

Can anyone guide me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is basically result of `Left join` minus result of `Inner Join`. This looks like a typical case of `merge` not `pd.concat`.

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `Left` join and `indicator` column as `True`. Pick rows which are present in `df1` only by choosing `left_only`:

```
In [1586]: df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)
Out[1586]: 
   contact_id subscription_id extra
1           3             ccc   NaN
2           4             ddd   NaN
3           5             eee   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
sub = pd.concat([df1, df2, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Problems in your code

1. You are concatting `df2` twice. (Though this doesn't matter since you then drop duplicates.)
2. If no set `subset` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), by default pandas will use all of the columns to identify duplicates.

Since `extra` column is unnecessary, you can do with boolean indexing

```py
df1 = df1.loc[~((df1['contact_id'].isin(df2['contact_id']))&(df1['subscription_id'].isin(df2['subscription_id'])))]
```

```
# print(df1)

   contact_id subscription_id
1           3             ccc
2           4             ddd
3           5             eee
```